# How to use pointDistance with a very large vector

Tags: r, distance, raster

I've got a big problem.

I've got a large raster (rows=180, columns=480, number of cells=86400)
At first I binarized it (so that there are only 1's and 0's) and then I labelled the clusters.(Cells that are 1 and connected to each other got the same label.)

Now I need to calculate all the distances between the cells, that are NOT 0.
There are quiet a lot and that's my big problem. 
I did this to get the coordinates of the cells I'm interested in (get the positions (i.e. cell numbers) of the cells, that are not 0):

```
V=getValues(label)
Vu=c(1:max(V))
pos=which(V %in% Vu)
XY=xyFromCell(label,pos)
```

This works very well. So XY is a matrix, which contains all the coordinates (of cells that are not 0). But now I'm struggling. I need to calculate the distances between ALL of these coordinates. Then I have to put each one of them in one of 43 bins of distances. It's kind of like this (just an example):

```
0<x<0.2     bin 1
0.2<x<0.4   bin2
```

When I use this:

```
pD=pointDistance(XY,lonlat=FALSE)
```

R says it's not possible to allocate vector of this size. It's getting too large. 
Then I thought I could do this (create an empty data frame df or something like that and let the function pointDistance run over every single value of XY):

```
for (i in 1:nrow(XY))
{pD=PointDistance(XY,XY[i,],lonlat=FALSE)
pDbin=as.matrix(table(cut(pD,breaks=seq(0,8.6,by=0.2),Labels=1:43)))
df=cbind(df,pDbin)
df=apply(df,1,FUN=function(x) sum(x))}
```

It is working when I try this with e.g. the first 50 values of XY.
But when I use that for the whole XY matrix it's taking too much time.(Sometimes this XY matrix contains 10000 xy-coordinates)
Does anyone have an idea how to do it faster?

Comment: Growing a dataframe by adding one column at a time is going to be slow as R has to make a copy each time. Preallocate the space required. But maybe you need more memory, or to make your problem simpler

Comment: Your last line looks like it could be replaced with `df=rowSums(df)`. That'll help a little.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will works fast or not. I recommend you try this:
Let say you have `dataframe` with value `0` or `1` in each cell. To find coordinates all you have to do is write the below code:

```
cord_matrix <- which(dataframe == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)
```

Now, you get the coordinate matrix with `row` index and `column` index. 
To find the euclidean distance use `dist()` function. Go through it. It will look like this:

```
dist_vector <- dist(cord_matrix)
```

It will return lower triangular matrix. can be transformed into vector/symmetric matrix. Now all you have to do is calculating bins according to your requirement.

Let me know if this works within the specific memory space.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried your auggestion and it really works faster. But when I want to convert this "dist" into a vector it's still too large. It says "can not allocate vector of this size". And I don't know how I could cut the "dist" values into bins without converting it into a vector before.

Comment: `dist()` function is actually return the output in vector format. check with `length()` and you can access every `dist()` value by `index`. So, I think you don't have to convert `dist()` output into vector explicitly as that may eat away your memory more.

Comment: But I just don't see how to calculate bins with that. I tried all day long to do it. But the cut-function doesn't work because this dist() is too large.

Comment: Try to delete variables after storing those on hard drive, using `rm()`before you start using `dist` value using `cut()`. Remove your large matrix from the workspace, coordinate matrix, and other stuff too. Check if that helps.